# How do I etl big data between 2 SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl

My primary datasource get 50M records per day. I need view record max delay about 5 minutes.

How I have best way to transfer data from primary SQL Server datasource to report SQL Server datasource.

At this time, I user merge join every 30seconds. But it seems effect to primary datasource performance.

Comment: Replication or data sync, maybe?

Comment: Replication would be an obvious choice. Have you done any of your own research?

Comment: I don’t use data sync because The method play with trigger. I think it causes slow down insert performance in primary datasource.

Comment: I also search replication method but I get more issues about performance.

Comment: Replication is usually efficient if it's set up correctly

Comment: @ADyson How about CDC? Is consume much CPU by using more tasks for capture log?

Comment: How is CDC related to your request to transfer data? I'm not sure why you are asking about that now. Anyway you could either read MS documentation, or ask in a DBA forum, or actually try it for yourself - that's probably the best way to get in-depth answers to a technical question about the product like that. It's not really a programming issue as such.

Answer (score 1):

The most common approach to minimize the load on your source server is to do periodic extracts using a timestamp, i.e. a simple SELECT ... `WHERE timestamp > previous-max-timestamp-extracted`.

The source table(s) need to provide a column that allows you to filter on un-extracted records. If that's completely impossible, you might extract e.g. the last hour's data into staging tables, and deduplicate with previously extracted records.

Yes, you could use CDC, but that's often more involved, and usually adds some restrictions.

Cheers, Kristian